# Trigger AntDesign (React) sider using custom button without this.state

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using AntD Sider ... but I don't want to use the sider button which makes it pop out. I'm currently writing this entire thing in a function so I can't use this.state as specified in the antd docs examples.

```
const [collapsed, setcollapsed] = useState(false);

return (
    <>
        <Sider collapsible collapsed={collapsed} onCollapse={setcollapsed} collapsedWidth={0} reverseArrow>
            <Menu>
                <Menu.Item></Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item></Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item></Menu.Item>
            </Menu
        </Sider
```

```
<Button shape="circle" style={styles.button} onClick={collapsed}>
    <MenuOutlined />
</Button>
```

Is there a way to make this button trigger the sider? ^

[image: I don't want this thing popping out like a sore thumb]

unlike this ^[*]

```
<Sider collapsible collapsed={collapsed} onCollapse={setcollapsed} collapsedWidth={0} reverseArrow></Sider>
```

Code for [*]

Comment: Could you link to said documentation?

Comment: https://ant.design/components/layout/ ... there's a sider section as you can see on the right side of the page

Answer (score 0):

Try this onClick handler please:

```
<Button shape="circle" style={styles.button} onClick={() => setcollapsed((prev) => !prev)}>
    <MenuOutlined />
</Button>
```

And remove onCollapse from here

```
<Sider collapsible collapsed={collapsed} collapsedWidth={0} reverseArrow>
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item></Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item></Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item></Menu.Item>
  </Menu
</Sider
```